# Javascript - document.createTextNode()

Tags: javascript, html

Using this strips my newLine characters

Is there an alternative to this that will render html?

```
 function viewCommentToggle( comment )
{
    theRow = document.getElementById("id"+comment.id);

    idx = 2;


        // Comment field
        cell = theRow.cells[idx];
        while( cell.childNodes.length > 0 ) cell.removeChild(cell.childNodes[0]);

            element = document.createTextNode(comment.comment);

        cell.appendChild(element);


         }
```

This is what Im concered with:

```
element = document.createTextNode(comment.comment);
```

just a fyi....this is what I did and it worked:

```
    function viewCommentToggle( comment )
{
    theRow = document.getElementById("id"+comment.id);

    idx = 2;


        // Comment field
        //cell = theRow.cells[idx];
        // while( cell.childNodes.length > 0 ) cell.removeChild(cell.childNodes[0]);

        cell = $("#id"+comment.id+" > td:eq("+idx+")");
        $(cell).empty();

        $(cell).html( comment.comment == null ? "" : comment.comment.replace(/\n/g,"<br/>").replace(/\r/g,"") );
```

Comment: yup, using jQuery does make it all a lot easier...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Newlines are only significant (AFAIK) within a `<pre>` block.

Outside of that, to force line breaks you'll have to split your string into separate lines and then create a text node followed by a `<br/>` for each one, i.e. something like:

```
var lines = text.split('\n');
var parent = document.body; // the node you want to insert the string into
for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; ++i) {
    parent.appendChild(document.createTextNode(lines[i]));
    parent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/WFTD6/

Comment: @DocHoliday nah, it's easy ;-)

Comment: ok..Im about to show you my javascript and show where Im creating the node....im passing in `comment` which has the html in it and it turning it to plain text

Comment: @DocHoliday you should be able to merge the code I've written above into your function - just rename my variables to match yours, and use my code to replace your last two lines.

Comment: need to split I guess comment.comment

Comment: What if I just want to keep whatever html is in comment.comment? Like say `<br>` or /n.....whatever

Comment: @DocHoliday then you need to use `node.innerHTML`, not `document.createTextNode()`